# Exception thrown when trying to access a web service (Weblogic) - java.lang.LinkageError

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, adobe

I've installed Adobe LiveCycle for Weblogic 10.3.4, and when I try to access one of the web services it deployed, I'm getting the following exception:

> Exception - java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method
>   "javax.wsdl.Definition.getBinding(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;)Ljavax/wsdl/Binding;"
>   the class loader (instance of
>   weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) of the current
>   class, org/apache/axis/wsdl/fromJava/Emitter, and the class loader
>   (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for resolved class,
>   javax/wsdl/Definition, have different Class objects for the type
>   javax/xml/namespace/QName used in the signature

I'm not a WebLogic guy nor a java one so I'm looking for a lead on this - what might be the problem and how can it be resolved, and above all - what might cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a conflict between the Web Service implementation bundled in you application and Weblogic's own implementation. Looks like Apache axis was used to build the application. Weblogic will try and use it's own implementation. It's possible the application was developed using a different web service specification version, or has Axis bundled. I don't know what Adobe LiveCycle uses. It may not be compatible. It might be worth trying to deploy the app in something that doesn't have a built in web service implementation (maybe Tomcat).